# How to add a favicon to my Website?

Tags: html, asp.net

I want to add a favicon to my ASP website like this

[image]

According to these topics:
[Image icon beside the site URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120420/image-icon-beside-the-site-url)
[How to put an image on the tab bar next to the title of the page on the browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15100634/how-to-put-an-image-on-the-tab-bar-next-to-the-title-of-the-page-on-the-browser)
I added my own `link` like this:

```
<head>
       <link rel="icon" href="/favicon-32x32.png"/>
</head>
```

But not showing anything? What's the wrong?

I've just tried my code again in notepad++ and it works fine, why then it is not working in my ASP.NET website?!

Comment: Have you seen this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10665893/how-to-add-image-with-title-of-an-html-page/10666010#10666010

Comment: You should probably do some research before asking a question like this...

Answer (score 4):

In some older browsers (e.g., Internet Explorer 5), that's all it takes. For the latest versions of Firefox, Internet Explorer and Chrome, however, you need to add two links to your favicon to the head in your HTML. If you are using a master page, the same two links would go in the head on the master page.:

```
<head runat="server">
                <title>My Website</title>
                <link runat="server" rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
                <link runat="server" rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/ico"/>
</head>
```

The reason you have two links to the same favicon is to make sure your favicon works with most browsers. Some, such as Firefox, will work with either link. Internet Explorer versions 6 and 7 are especially picky. If you use both links, however, one is bound to work in almost any browser.

Answer (score 3):

you can you use the different **favicon** types below:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="http://example.com/favicon.ico" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="http://example.com/favicon.png" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/gif" href="http://example.com/favicon.gif" />
```

depending on what file you want to use as icon of your site.

For other formats of **favicon**, you can refer on this [site](http://iconhandbook.co.uk/reference/examples/favicons/)

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I could think of, is to try and add `type="image/png"` to the link element. Make sure that the image is in the same directory as the file you are referring to.

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon-32x32.png"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create your own 16x16 favicon

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon.png"/>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="http://eg.com/favicon.png"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you want favorite icon with favicon.ico name (ico extension), and place it inside the root folder.

If not in root folder, you need to explicitly create a **link** tag. For example,

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" 
   href="//cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico?v=4f32ecc8f43d">
```

FYI, you cannot simply rename file extension png to ico. Instead, you want to convert it in correct format.

I normally use this site to convert png to ico - http://convertico.com/